# My containerized Java RabbitMQ consumer stops consuming

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have written a Java RabbitMQ using Spring Boot and containerized it as a Docker container. When I run the container on my MacBook it works perfectly fine consuming all queued messages with its 32 concurrent consumers. However, when I deploy the same Docker image and run it on our production server it stops consuming after a while.

[image]

The above image is where it has stopped. I have configured the RabbitMQ client to use 32 concurrent consumers with a prefetch count of 8 which explains the 8 * 32 = 256 unacked messages.

```
listener:
  simple:
    concurrency: 32
    max-concurrency: 64
    prefetch: 8
    retry:
      enabled: true
      multiplier: 2
      max-attempts: 20
      stateless: true
      initial-interval: 1s
      max-interval: 30s
    acknowledge-mode: auto
    default-requeue-rejected: true
```

I can confirm that there is absolutely no load on the cpu whatsoever and the consumer implementation is not causing the threads to wait as far as I know. I also have tried toggling retry enabled to false to see if that would help but it didn't.

It totally works fine when I run it on my MacBook in which case I also run the RabbitMQ image locally. The production server runs on `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)` and the base image for the Docker Java container is `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`.

The production server hosts both a RabbitMQ image `rabbitmq:3.7-management-alpine` and the Java containerized application on it using `--net=host` networking mode. The production server is also configured using CSF firewall with a default HTTP/HTTPS webserver configuration.

I also found an answer referring to the maximum allowed open files setting on the server but changing the hard file limit using `ulimit` didn't have any effect either. The Alpine docker container has a hard file limit of 1048576 so that should suffice. On my MacBook however it is `unlimited`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check how many consumers are actually registered in RabbitMQ admin UI. If there are consumers, but nothing happens, try to remotely debug/profile your service to check thread pools.

Comment: We had once a very nasty problem that a OOME somehow made consuming threads in our application "zombies". They were still kind of alive (there were registered consumers in RabbitMQ), but were not doing anything. We've found this out by analyzing thread pools remotely. Unfortunately I don't remember how exactly we did it, I think it involved remote debugging or profiling.

Comment: It would appear that the messages are being delivered and either processed but not ack'd or not processed at all. Can you do more debugging to figure out what is going on in your consumers?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem was not due to RabbitMQ's inner workings, networking or file descriptor limits after all.

After some remote debugging using SSH local port forwarding the culprit proved to be `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` being called inside a Docker container. Apparently this blocks indefinitely without any further indication of what's going on. Changing it to `new SecureRandom()` made the problem go away.

Here's my `Dockerfile` to further indicate my source of randomness:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD libs/app-0.1.0.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

I think that using `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` bypasses the use of `urandom` and reverts back to `random` thus exhibiting the blocking behavior. Some more interesting reading about the differences between `/dev/./random` and `/dev/./urandom` can be found here: http://www.thezonemanager.com/2015/07/whats-so-special-about-devurandom.html